# How to avoid creating duplicate records in join table with has_many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, associations

I have two models `Physician`, `Patient` and a join model `Appointment` and the association is like as follows:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :patients
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

I want to update `appoinment_data` in the `appointment` table when there is a new 
entry in the `appointment` table.

So in the rails console:

```
a = Physician.last
#<Physician id: 1, name: "Hamza", address: "Pune", created_at: "2017-02-22 07:07:10", updated_at: "2017-02-22 07:07:10">

a.update(patients_attributes: [{ name: 'Prajakta', disease: 'Fever', appointments_attributes: [{appointment_data: DateTime.now}]}])
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "patients" ("name", "disease", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Prajakta"], ["disease", "Fever"], ["created_at", "2017-02-22 08:30:22.321863"], ["updated_at", "2017-02-22 08:30:22.321863"]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "appointments" ("appointment_data", "patient_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["appointment_data", "2017-02-22 08:30:22.311198"], ["patient_id", 5], ["created_at", "2017-02-22 08:30:22.326373"], ["updated_at", "2017-02-22 08:30:22.326373"]]
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "appointments" ("physician_id", "patient_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["physician_id", 1], ["patient_id", 5], ["created_at", "2017-02-22 08:30:22.333624"], ["updated_at", "2017-02-22 08:30:22.333624"]]
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

It is creating two `records` in the `appointment` table.
One record with `appointment_data` and `patient_id`. Other is with `physician_id` and `patient_id`.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a workaround by placing `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. My associations are now like this:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :patients
end
```

And i did this in the console:

```
a = Physician.last
a.update(appointment_attributes: [{appointment_data: DateTime.now, patient_attributes: {name: 'Rajesh', disease: 'fever'}}])
```

It is now creating only one record in the `appointments` table.